# What is datetime in HTML?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was learning HTML from a book and a noticed an example,

```
<del datetime="20040329">fluffy kitten</del>
```

What does datetime mean and what does it do?

Comment: http://www.html5videotutorial.com/del-tag.html

Answer (score 4):

A deleted text, with a date and time of when the text was deleted:

```
<p>My favorite color is <del datetime="2009-01-08T22:55:03Z">blue</del>
<ins>red</ins>!</p>
```

more info http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/del/datetime

http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/del

Answer (score 2):

The datetime attribute specifies the date and time when the text was deleted.

This links may help you

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_del_datetime.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_time.asp

```
<p>My favorite color is <del datetime="2009-01-08T22:55:03Z">blue</del>
<ins>red</ins>!</p>
```

Answer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/del.html

> The del element represents a range of text that has been deleted from a document.
>
> datetime - The date and time when the text was deleted. A valid date-time as defined in [RFC 3339], with these additional qualifications:
>
> - the literal letters T and Z in the date/time syntax must always be uppercase
> - the date-fullyear production is instead defined as four or more digits representing a number greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

It shows when some text was deleted, [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_del_datetime.asp). The deleted text is crossed out.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime attribute specifies the date and time when the text was deleted. It no visual effect in ordinary web browsers, 
**Syntax**

```
<del datetime="YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD">
```